# How to get the column header of attribute table

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, vb.net, vb

I have a simple vb.net code which gets all the layer names present in the ArcMap and displays it in a vb form combobox. My question is if I select a layer name that is present in my combobox it should get me the column headings of attribute table of the selected layer. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, please take the community tour here: gis.stackexchange.com/tour.  For coding question please provide your best code attempt within the question and note where you are stuck.  This forum does not provide code it for me answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the fields of a layer you need to get a handle on the FeatureClass. It has a property called fields that returns an IFields object. There are [worked samples in the API help file](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#96fc82fb-f746-4226-bba4-801f3f617e58.htm).